# How Python Generators Save Memory And Time?

Tags: python, memory, generator

I'm working on Generators. I can't easily take in some informations I learnt.

```
y = []
def x(a: int) -> None:
    for x in range(a):
        y.append(x)

def z(a):
    for i in range(a):
        yield i

x(10**6)
t = z(10**6)
print(next(t))
print(next(t))
```

Comparing two code,

**first code;**

- y is creating list object by setting []
- And in for loop y.append() function calls 10**6 times and do operations
- If I want to reach any value of y, y will go to heap memory and retrieve data I just requested

**second code;**

All values will yield when I call t = z(10**6)? or It will yield when I call next function I mean when I use next function it will go the generator and yield next value and get it from there? Does it remember where it left with a pointer? Does it delete the value after next function used I mean after calling print(next(t)) it will delete just after the operation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `z` does not save anything. A `range` object is an generator-like iterable already, at least in Python 3. And `x` is even worse since it stores **all** value in a list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming CPython here.

In example 1, `y` is backed by a heap-allocated C `ListObject` structure, which is (with some accoutrements) a `length` integer and an array of `Object*` pointers.

Notwithstanding error checks, something like `y[1234]` ends up doing the analogue of `y->entries[1234]`.

In example 2, calling the generator function allocates a generator, which contains the state of the generator function.

Calling `next()` on the generator will run the generator function code until the next `yield`. At that point, the function's state (and further down, `range()`'s, which is a generator too), state is retained, and the value is returned via `next()` to the caller. For a generator, the values themselves aren't stored (unless you do e.g. modify an array).

Hope that helps.

Comment: So is it like this?
1) Python sets a flag to remember z(a) is not regular Python function, it is genarator so it will not run like normal functions.
2) When I set t = z(10**6), it sets its gi_frame.f_lasti = -1 to point out the generator hasn't begun yet
3) When I call next(t) for the first time, it goes to the function and yield, take values from the heap memory where allocated and after take it, it is deleted
4) Its gi_frame.f_lasti values changes to remember where it left off? Sorry I just want to know what is going on exactly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Approximately like that. Considering Python is a garbage collected language, "heap memory" is not really a concept here. Remember that local values within the generator are remembered too, not just the last insn.

Comment: To sum up, the next() caller fetch the value by calling the generator def z(). Btw I red the local values conctept I couldn't get it as well. When I tried, I couldn't get any local values in any attempt. Thank you for detailed answers. And making me sure what I actually am doing!

Comment: def a(myList):
    count=0
    for i in myList:count+=2;print('local : ',count);yield i
aG=a(range(5))
print('return :',next(aG))
print('return :',next(aG))
for i in aG:print('for : ',i)##  You can see that generator remembers the local variable 'count' too along with the yield value 'i'.